# Получение данных из потока

Tags: javascript, node.js

Приветствую. 
Пытаюсь получить данные из потока.

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
    let chunk = String(process.stdin.read());
    console.log(chunk);
});
```

Мне возвращается

```
Input:
10 2
Your output:
10 2
null
```

Как избавиться от null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, проверить, что `process.stdin.read()` вернул что-то полезное (не `null`).

Естественно, проверить надо до каста к строке, а не после. Примерно так:

```
process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();

  if (!chunk) {
    return;
  }

  chunk = "" + chunk;

  console.log(chunk);
});
```

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, ну так я и вывед в консоль, что это true. Не понял, что не так.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, можно более подробные комментарии. Насколько я понимаю, `process.stdin.read()` вернул `null` (сам null, не строку, не буфер, а null), он его без проверки скастил к строке `"null"` и вывел. Я не прав?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, так проверять надо до каста, а не после. Я же написал, что сравнить надо `process.stdin.read()` с `null`, а не `chunk` с `"null"`.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, уточнил ответ.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, минус-то уберёшь?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, но он же был правильным)

Answer (score 3):

**Почему это происходит?**

Событие `readable` выбрасывается не только в случае, когда доступна новая порция данных, но и когда достигнут конец потока:

Вот что об этом сказано в [официальной документации](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_event_readable):

> The 'readable' event will also be emitted once the end of the stream data has been reached but before the 'end' event is emitted.

Далее, если вы пытаетесь читать из потока после того, как достигнут конец потока, метод `stream.read` вернет `null`.

Позволю себе снова процитировать документацию [документацию](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size):

> Note: Calling `stream.read([size])` after the `'end'` event has been emitted will return `null`. No runtime error will be raised.

Иными словами, возврат `null` - это штатное поведение readable-потока.

---

**Что делать?**

Тут есть сразу несколько вариантов:

1. Метод `stream.read` возвращает `null` только в одном случае. Вы можете в явном виде проверять результат `stream.read` на это значение:

   ```
   process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
       let chunk = process.stdin.read();
       if (null !== chunk) {
           console.log(chunk.toString());
       }
   });
   ```
2. Можно использовать поток в [другом (*flowing*) режиме](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_two_modes) и получать данные по событию [`data`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_event_data):

   ```
   process.stdin.on('data', (chunk) => {
       console.log(chunk.toString());
   });
   ```

Comment: Хм.. а во втором случае при условии, что он использовал `setEncoding` разве `chunk` не будет сразу строкой?

Comment: Будет, как впрочем и в первом. С другой стороны, в ответе я не использую `setEncoding`, так что преобразование к строке необходимо

Comment: <s>Тогда зачем приводишь?</s> Ok.